# Thymeleaf-Spring th:block and th:each does not run again if an error occurs

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am validating a field that is where the name of a role is defined. This is in a form is sent via post. The point is that when an error occurs and call again:

```
modelAndView.setViewName ("admin/role");
return modelAndView;
```

It does not regenerate the list of `<td>` within `th: block`. But when the process is done correctly, it shows me my normal page.

**Successful process:**[image: Success]

**If an error occurs:**[image: Error]

**GET METHOD:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/role", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView role(Model model){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    List<Page> pages = pageService.getAllPages();
    Role role = new Role();
    modelAndView.addObject("role", role);
    modelAndView.addObject("pages", pages);
    modelAndView.addObject("userName", user.getName());
    modelAndView.setViewName("admin/role");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**POST METHOD:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/role", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewRole(@Valid Role role,BindingResult bindingResult,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "pgids" , required = false) Integer [] pgids
                                  ){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    modelAndView.addObject("userName", user.getName());

    Role roleExist = roleService.findByAuthority(role.getAuthority());
    if (roleExist != null){
        bindingResult
                .rejectValue("authority","error.app_role", "There is already a role registered with the name provided");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            modelAndView.setViewName("admin/role");
    }else{
        if(pgids != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pgids.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(pgids[i]);
            }
        }
        roleService.saveRole(role, pgids);

        List<Page> pages = pageService.getAllPages();
        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Role has been created successfully");
        modelAndView.addObject("role", new Role());
        modelAndView.addObject("pages", pages);
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin/role");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/admin/role}" method="post" role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 bottommargin-sm">
        <label>Name of the Role</label>
        <label class="errormsg" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('role.authority')}" th:errors="${role.authority}"></label>
        <input type="text" th:field="${role.authority}" class="sm-form-control"
               placeholder="Example Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Catalogue of Pages</label>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-sm-2 center">Asign</th>
                <th class="col-sm-4 center">Name</th>
                <th class="col-sm-6 center">URL</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <th:block th:each="page : ${pages}">
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-2 center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="pgids" th:value="${page.id}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-4 center" th:utext="${page.name}"></td>
                    <td class="col-sm-6 center" th:utext="${page.url}"></td>
                </tr>
            </th:block>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="button nomargin rightmargin-sm button-reef-blue">Create
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label th:utext="${successMessage}" class="successmsg"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the bottom, it was my mistake not to add the variable pages once it enters bindingResult.hasErrors (). So that 'if' is as follows:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            List<Page> pages = pageService.getAllPages();
            modelAndView.addObject("pages", pages);
            modelAndView.setViewName("admin/role");
    }
```

Comment: When `bindingResult.hasErrors()` is true, you don't set model object `pages`, so why are you surprised that `${pages}` is null and `th:each` has nothing to iterate?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Why are you using `<th:block>` instead of just putting the `th:each` on the `<tr>` itself?

Comment: @Andreas That is why I am asking for help, it is a detail that I did not contemplate. For you it was too obvious, I appreciate your help, but neither is it to belittle my question, or yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form with invalid data

```
bindingResult.hasErrors()
```

will return true and you do not enter the section of code where you add the pages due to your if/else clause.

So the variable

> pages

contains no data and your `th:each` loop will do nothing.

If you want to print the pages even when invalid data was entered you could just remove your `else`.

Comment: You're very right, I completely forgot that part. Thank you.